# How shrink file size when Wordpress resizes an image?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress, imagick

I've optimized an image that is `1280px x 800px` in width/height and is `150kb` in file size. I have used `add_image_size` to Wordpress to make different thumbnail, small and large versions of the uploaded image. However, when Wordpress sizes this image, it's much bigger in file size despite being smaller! I get this:

```
/* I only specified widths because the images keep the same ratio */ 

IMAGE NAME      WIDTH       FILE SIZE
--------------  -------     ----------
my-small-size   480px       112kb
my-medium-size  768px       211kb
my-large-size   1280px      150kb (I uploaded this version)
```

I have installed imagick, but don't know if Wordpress is using it. Is there a way to improve the compression that Wordpress uses?

**EDIT: These are `png` images.**

Comment: There are a lot of plugins that do that already.

Comment: have you tried wp-smush.it ?

Comment: @jeroen no there aren't. I looked at all the plugns I could find and all of them let you specify either a size for "small", "medium" and "large" but not your custom image sizes, or they only shrink jpegs. None of them seem to allow compression on PNGs for all the custom image sizes.

Comment: Are you sure? This looks promising for example: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/10-best-image-optimization-plugins-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-site/

Comment: @AhmadAssaf I don't want to install a plugin that relies on connection to another company's site. a good suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: @jeroen That plugin works by sending your image to their site for compression. This appears to cause big problems when that connection goes down for people using the plugin. I need something that works entirely within the wordpress it's installed on.

Comment: I haven't tried any of them :-) But I would guess WordPress is using GD so you could do a quick search for `imagepng` and see if that is something you can hook into yourself with a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The default quality when saving in WordPress is 90%.

If you want to change this, stick the following code in your functions.php for your theme:

```
function reduce_wp_image_quality( $quality ) {
  return 60; // default is 90% quality
}
add_filter('wp_editor_set_quality', 'reduce_wp_image_quality');
add_filter('jpeg_quality', 'reduce_wp_image_quality');
```

This should affect all thumbnails generated by WordPress.

--

`wp_editor_set_quality` is located in:

- wp-includes/class-wp-image-edito.php:228

`jpeg_quality` is located in:

- wp-includes/class-wp-image-edito.php:241
- wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php:319

Comment: Sorry, I left out that these are PNG images.

Comment: `wp_editor_set_quality` is used for all image types. I'm not sure if that actually affects PNGs though, since they are lossless... To do custom optimization, you'll need to hook your plugin off of [wp_image_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor). I'm really not sure where to go from there, though. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Use JPEG images, that compress well. PNG will not help with compressing size when reducing the dimensions.